# How do I access my rails database from a task in lib/tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, database, scripting

I am developing an app that needs to send text messages, so I have carrier information stored in a database.  I also need that information in an XML file for client side code to read.  To make this happen, I am writing a script that reads the carrier information from the DB and creates an XML file in the config directory.  I felt this script would fit best in lib/tasks.

I need to access the database from this script, but I want to use some object to access it.  If I use

```
db = Mysql.new("domain", "username", "password", "database")
```

I will have to keep multiple versions for different environments because I do not use MySQL all the time.  That would be very sloppy.  I am sure there is a way to do this.  I tried to just access the object...this is what I have so far:

```
RAILS_HOME = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),"../.."))
RAILS_CONFIG = "#{RAILS_HOME}/config"

f = File.new("#{RAILS_CONFIG}/mls_widget_config.xml", "w")
carriers = Carrier.find_all
f.write carriers
f.close
```

But Carrier is not defined, which makes sense.  How can I give this script access to the the Carrier object in the DB?

Also as a side, if anyone knows how to easily convert what I read from the DB into proper XML that would be great.  I was going to write something custom real quick.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enable a Rake task to access your models by defining your task like this:

```
task :my_task => :environment do
  # Task code
end
```

Note the `=> :environment`, which grants this access. You can then instruct your Rake task to use different environments this way:

```
rake RAILS_ENV=development my_task
rake RAILS_ENV=production my_task
```

As for XML serialization, you can use the built-in `to_xml` method, such as:

```
Carrier.all.to_xml
```

Note that the method `.all` is a recent addition to Rails, and is an alias for `.find(:all)`.

Answer (score 2):

You're actually almost there; I'd just recommend requiring your Rails environment as part of the script, like so:

```
RAILS_HOME = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),"../.."))
RAILS_CONFIG = "#{RAILS_HOME}/config"
require "#{RAILS_CONFIG}/environment"
```

Now you should have access to all of your domain structure. Rails also includes default XML serialization through the use of the `to_xml` method call; try `Carrier.find(:all).to_xml`.

Answer (score 2):

By convention, lib/tasks is usually reserved for rake tasks - you might want to put your library code in its own directory. lib/messaging, maybe?

Are you running an old version of Rails? find_all doesn't work in recent versions: 'find(:all)' or just 'all' are the methods nowadays.

```
File.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/mls_widget_config.xml", "w") do |f|
  Carrier.all.each { |carrier| f.puts carrier.to_xml }
end
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how to link to the model class, as the question asks.